# Time and Space Complexity for PCP and Halting Problem

Tags: complexity-theory, theory, number-theory

So PCP is semi-decidable and undecidable and Halting Problem is undecidable. 
Is it even possible to name a time complexity for them, like NP or expTime?

And what about space Complexity: are they in Pspace?

Comment: Undecidable problems are in neither of the mentioned complexity classes, because the definition of these classes requires there to be an algorithm that decides the problem in the first place.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a purely theoretical question about decision theory / complexity theory and is not programming related.

Comment: See https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/56737/complexity-classes-of-undecidable-turing-machines.

Comment: @walnut that makes sense thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as @walnut stated they are in neither of the mentioned complexity classes because the classes requires there to be an algorithm that decides the problem in the first place.Thank you for your answer :)